# Record an audio from the web

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording

I want to record (`Record-Pause/Resume-Stop`) an audio from the web. I have tried [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) but still it's not compatible for all the browsers like IE and safari. Even though it supports for firefox and chrome, different behavior on chrome (works perfect) and firefox (posted an another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804427/mediarecorder-api-starts-recording-an-audio-after-few-seconds-delay-web)). I can use flash but that would be last choice if there is no possibilities with HTML5 or JS. Is there any opensource JS plug-in or library to achieve this? It will be great if someone has the fix for firefox issue.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this a while back: [JSSoundRecorder](https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder)

I had it record and export to a WAV file. If you find a browser that doesn't support it, you likely shouldn't care about that browser.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not provide pause and resume option.

Comment: I believe when I did the project that used that, I simply recorded two separate versions, then merged them when the user hit "stop".

Comment: I tested this sample http://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/ , still i'm facing record time delay (not all the time). What could be the reason? Can you check this in your firefox multiple record?

Comment: Huh uninstalling the firefox from v50 to  v 49.0.1 solved the record delay issue.

Comment: Yes, the mentioned issue has resolved by uninstall and install the Firefox.

Comment: @iLaYaツ can you mark my answer as the right answer?